# Show icons only in drop-down of custom Spinner

Tags: java, android

I Have created a `Spinner` using adapter with icons and text. Everything is displayed correctly but there is a requirement that Activity spinner should show text only. Icons should only appear in the drop-down list.
 It this possible to implement?

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
 Context context; 
 int flags[]; 
 String[] countryNames; 
 LayoutInflater inflter; 

 public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] countryNames) { 
 this.context = applicationContext; 
 this.flags = flags; 
 this.countryNames = countryNames; 
 inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext)); 
 } 

 [id3844467|@Override] 
 public int getCount() { 
 return flags.length; 
 } 

 [id3844467|@Override] 
 public Object getItem(int i) { 
 return null; 
 } 

 [id3844467|@Override] 
 public long getItemId(int i) { 
 return 0; 
 } 

 [id3844467|@Override] 
 public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) { 
 view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null); 
 ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView); 
 TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView); 
 icon.setImageResource(flags[i]); 
 names.setText(countryNames[i]); 
 return view; 
 } 
}
```

XML

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
>  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>  android:orientation="horizontal"> 
>
>  <ImageView 
>  android:id="@+id/imageView" 
>  android:layout_width="40dp" 
>  android:layout_height="40dp" 
>  android:padding="5dp" 
>  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> // for check that icon existing
>
>  <TextView 
>  android:id="@+id/textView" 
>  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>  android:layout_gravity="center" 
>  android:padding="0dp" 
>  android:text="Demo" // for check that text existing
>  android:textColor="#000" /> 
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: can you please explain this part :"but there is a desire that would Activity spinner showed text only and icons only appeared in the drop-down list" ?

Comment: could you please explain properly what you want exactly or show a screen shot as per you requirement

Comment: I mean, that default spinner have text and arrow. I've created adapter with images and texts. but now when I closed the drop-down list, the image also appears. I.e. is it possible to make that when spinner closed - the spinner image is not shown, but shown in the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

Set these two property in spinner hopeFully it will work

```
android:dropDownHeight="0dp" 
android:dropDownWidth="0dp"
```

Comment: Please, let me know, I should set this property for ImageView?

Comment: set these two property in spinner view inside xml. your have a spinner for which you set the adapter so  these are the spinner property set it inside xml where you defined you Spinner View

Comment: unfortunatly its just do not let dropdown open. its not work

Answer (score 0):

i'am not sure but change your getItemId like  this :

```
@Override 
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}
```

and don't return null on getItem

Comment: why  you don't extends ArrayAdapter<String> and implements SpinnerAdapter ?