# Custom Spinner with icons in drop-down list, but only text (without icon) when it closed

Tags: java, android, spinner

Have created a Spinner with icons and text. Icons is appear when Spinner opened and closed.
How to make Spinner with icons in drop-down list, but only text (without icon) when it closed like on screenshots below.
Thanks in advance.

[Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPGNS.jpg)
[Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTWpS.jpg)

Comment: Where is screenshot man ?

Comment: Where is screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, screenshots added

Comment: Instead of `Spinner` use an ordinary `TextView` with [`PopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html).

Comment: Thanks, in process)

Answer (score 0):

Change visibility of selected items textview on spinner.onItemselected method.Here is a example code

```
 campaignSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) adapterView.getChildAt(0);
            TextView selectedText = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.spinner_campaign_text);
            TextView selectedId = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.spinner_campaign_position);
            if (selectedText != null) {
                selectedText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                selectedId.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Dear FnR, l have to add it in my main layout code where I describe spinner? Additionally, I asked it before, here is my adapter code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208519/show-icons-only-in-drop-down-of-custom-spinner

Comment: yes. Use it in activity or fragment wherever you setting adapter to your spinner.

Comment: this is not a adapter operation. You have to handle it on where spinner is

Comment: Thank you for replay, unfortunately didn't solve it. So now creating textview with popupwindow

Comment: Okey.Its up to you but i think you missing some point cause this is what i used for what you want exactly